# InstallShield - Accessing CustomActionData in C# WIX DTF custom action dll

Tags: c#

Attempting to use functions in a WIX DTF custom action dll from InstallShield 2016. The process is identical to executing deferred custom actions in a "Managed Code" type custom action, except that for DTF access, one must create a "New MSI DLL" type custom action. The property name in the custom action must match the name of the function in the referenced custom action dll. If they don't match, CustomActionData will be empty.

For either custom action type, a "set property" action must first be executed, which sets the value of CustomActionData. Then, the function associated with the custom action is executed and retrieves the value previously set in CustomActionData.

My property and my function have the same name (SetRegionalServerUrl), and I call a "set property" custom action first but CustomActionData is empty when the custom action's function attempts to read its contents.

This works fine when using a "managed code" type custom action dll, so I'm hoping someone can suggest things to try, or point out what I've missed.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I'm able to do Session.Log() calls from the function, and the MSI log shows that session.CustomActionData.Keys.Count = 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an action executed in the deferred context, then the normal variables are not available. You have to wrap all of them into `CustomActionData`:
http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp22/helplibrary/ActionExecutionOptions.htm

What you'd do is define a `CustomActionData` to be equal to a collation of the original properties and then parse that in your actual action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... I mentioned that this is a deferred action, and that I call a "set property" custom action immediately before this deferred action. My understanding is that this sets CustomActionData so that it can be accessed from the function associated with the deferred custom action. Again, this works fine for a "managed code" type custom action, but not for a "new msi" type of custom action that calls into a WIX DTF custom action dll. If there's something different required for the latter, then I'd appreciate any info you could provide.

Comment: Sounds like you may be saying that CustomActionData is not already defined and must be declared before setting property values to it? This contradicts everything that I've read, so I hope I'm just misunderstanding what you meant.